# Put text on shape in javafx with an AnchorPane

Tags: javafx

I have an ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectanlges= new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

there are several rectangles in this arrayList...   with

```
anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);
```

I do show the shapes... but I want to put a text on every rectangle... I tried it with

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++) {
    Text text = new Text("test");
                text.setFill(Color.GREEN);

                StackPane stack = new StackPane();

                stack.getChildren().addAll(rectangles.get(i), text);
}
```

but I have difficulties showing them like

```
 anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);
```

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: *"difficulties showing them"* Could you add some details... Because you aren't even trying to connect the `StackPane`s to the rest of the scene graph in that code snippet.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem - how can i show a stackpane inside an anchorpane?

Answer (score 0):

Just add every `StackPane` to `anchorpane` instead of every `Rectangle` and add the offset of the `Rectangle`s as `AnchorPane` layout parameters to the `StackPane`.

Example:

```
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();

List<Rectangle> rectangles = Arrays.asList(new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50), new Rectangle(200, 100, 70, 300));

anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(rectangles.stream().map(rect -> {
    Text text = new Text("test");
    text.setFill(Color.GREEN);

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(rect, text);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(stackPane, rect.getX());
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(stackPane, rect.getY());
    return stackPane;
}).toArray(StackPane[]::new));
```

Alternatively you could use `Label`s with background:

```
anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(rectangles.stream().map(rect -> {
    Label text = new Label("test");

    text.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
    text.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    text.setPrefSize(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(text, rect.getX());
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(text, rect.getY());
    return text;
}).toArray(Label[]::new));
```

Comment: isn't there an easier way to put a text on a rectangle?

Comment: You could use a label... Or you could just add the text and bind it's layout coordinates to the rectangle. But I don't really see what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: @user3650191: In case you're not familiar with `Stream`s/lambda expressions: You can easily rewrite the code by using a enhanced `for` loop with element name `rect` and adding the `Node` to a list instead of the `return` statement. Otherwise I really can't see why this approach isn't simple enough. Converting non-working code to working code by adding/ modifying 5 lines is all you can hope for in most cases (that is unless there really is a simpler way, but here you have to "tell" the text that it should be psitioned at the same position), especially if the original code was that short...

Comment: Ok it worked - But when I try to change it's background color from outside, it does not change - do I have to reload the anchorPane?

Comment: @user3650191: No, changing the color automatically updates the scene graph (that is if you do it from fx application thread of course). You have to change the `Node`s actually in the scene graph however. In the second code snippet the color does not automatically change, it you modify the `Rectangle`s. If you change the position with the first approach, the scene wouldn't update either. For that you'd need to add listeners/use bindings. But that's the drawback of not using the required `Node` types from the start...

Comment: so, what I have to do when I use your second solution, to change its color

Comment: I did it :) but when I remove my anchorpane with anchorpane.clear(); the text is still visible, how can I clear it too?

Comment: @user3650191: There is no `clear()` method in [`AnchorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html).

Comment: sorry i meant: anchorpane.getChildren().removeAll(rectangles);
and with rectangles.clear(); I can clear the arraylist

Comment: but how can I remove the text ( labe ) too?

Comment: could you help me using a timeline in my newest question?

Comment: How can I change the attributes of text label like position